# Prospective algorithmic approach for this image in OpenCV

Tags: algorithm, opencv, computer-vision

I am looking for advice from people having extensive experience with computer vision. I have a collection of ultrasonographic B&W images like the one below (without the stars and dotted line):

[image: ultrasonographic image of blood vessel]

What I would like to do is detect the contour of a blood vessel (for example, the one highlighted by the yellow star). Of course my first step would be to define the ROI and maximize the contrast. But what would then be the best algorithm to use? Segmentation with the watershed algorithm? Something else?
I am little unsettled because of the image blur...

---

### Edit:

As requested in the comments, here would be an example of source and result images:
[image: source]
[image: result]

Comment: Can you describe your problem better? Please put an image without stars or anything. And also put another image that has manually drawn contours. So we can understand what the exact problem is. If you place an image and ask us to help detect contours of a blood vessel, we could not help because we don't know which part is blood vessel. Also putting just a star does not show blood vessel. It is just a star.

Comment: watershed might work nicely, but requires (manual) initial center points, like your stars there

Comment: @berak Thanks! I suspected so, from what I read in the OpenCV docs. Would you know of an alternative to avoid the initial center point problem and make it fully automated, even with maybe inferior performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is a simple approach to your problem, if I understood you correctly. My result is shown below.

[image: The result of the code I have posted]

And here is the code

```
int max_area_threshold = 10000;
int min_area_threshold = 1000;
float rational_threshold = 0.7;

cv::Mat img = cv::imread("sample.jpg", CV_8UC1);
cv::Mat img_binary;

//Create binary imae by tresholding
cv::threshold(img, img_binary, 25, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

//Invert black-white
cv::bitwise_not(img_binary, img_binary);

//Eliminating small segments
cv::erode(img_binary, img_binary, cv::Mat(), cv::Point(-1, -1), 2, 1, 1);
cv::dilate(img_binary, img_binary, cv::Mat(), cv::Point(-1, -1), 1, 1, 1);

//Find contours
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
cv::findContours( img_binary, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
{
    if(contours[i].size() < 5)
        continue;

    //Fit ellipse to contour
    cv::RotatedRect boundRect = cv::fitEllipse(contours[i]);

    //Check the squareness of the bounding box
    if(abs((boundRect.size.width / (float)boundRect.size.height)-1.0) > rational_threshold)
        continue;

    //Elliminate too big segments
    if(boundRect.boundingRect().area() > max_area_threshold)
        continue;

    //Elliminate too small segments
    if(boundRect.boundingRect().area() < min_area_threshold)
        continue;

    drawContours(img, contours, i, cv::Scalar(255), 0.2, 8, hierarchy, 0, cv::Point() );
}

cv::imwrite("result.jpg", img);
```

I hope it helps.